# Sign application before uploading to android market

Tags: android, google-play, sign

I have uploaded my first application to android market. Before doing that, I had to sign the application. This is my first time so there are something I have not known.
1.In the future, if I update new version for my application, do I have to sign for the new version or not? 
2. Can I use the same key for all applications or do I have to sign for each application one unique key?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can sign all of your applications with same signing key, and to update your application package on android market you need to sign application with same signing keys, which has been used in previous version.

Comment: So you mean that it is a must, or just need?

Comment: first answer for same signing key for multiple apps it is upto your wish, for second answer to update application on android market it is must.